# How to create a LocalDB instance for NEventStore

Tags: localdb, neventstore

I'm trying to use LocalDb with NEventStore but, even though I think I have set-up the database correctly, I keep getting the following exception:
`NEventStore.Persistence.StorageUnavailableException: Invalid object name 'Snapshots'`.

In code I configure NEventStore to use the database like this:

```
this.EventStore = Wireup.Init()
               .LogToOutputWindow()
               .UsingInMemoryPersistence()
               .UsingSqlPersistence("DefaultConnection")
               .WithDialect(new MsSqlDialect())
               .UsingJsonSerialization()
               .LogToOutputWindow()
               .Build();
```

I have the following database connection in my web.config file:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\MyDatabase.mdf;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

And using Visual Studio I've added an SqlServerDatabase (MyDatabase.mdf) to the App_Data folder of my Asp.net MVC 5 project. NEventStore seems to be able to open the database (if I remove MyDatabase.mdf from my project I get a different exception). But it seems its unable to initialize the database correctly. When I browse the database, after running into the error message, I see that no tables have been created.

What makes this extra strange is that, [if this document is correct](https://github.com/NEventStore/NEventStore.Persistence.SQL/blob/master/src/NEventStore.Persistence.Sql/SqlDialects/MsSqlStatements.resx),  `Snapshots` should be the second table made. So it seems it has no problem creating the first one.

The complete stack trace for the StorageUnavailableException

```
   at NEventStore.Persistence.Sql.SqlDialects.PagedEnumerationCollection.OpenNextPage() in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\38b1777f2112a252\src\NEventStore\Persistence\Sql\SqlDialects\PagedEnumerationCollection.cs:line 200
   at NEventStore.Persistence.Sql.SqlDialects.PagedEnumerationCollection.MoveToNextRecord() in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\38b1777f2112a252\src\NEventStore\Persistence\Sql\SqlDialects\PagedEnumerationCollection.cs:line 146
   at NEventStore.Persistence.Sql.SqlDialects.PagedEnumerationCollection.System.Collections.IEnumerator.MoveNext() in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\38b1777f2112a252\src\NEventStore\Persistence\Sql\SqlDialects\PagedEnumerationCollection.cs:line 70
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at NEventStore.Persistence.Sql.SqlPersistenceEngine.GetSnapshot(String bucketId, String streamId, Int32 maxRevision) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\38b1777f2112a252\src\NEventStore\Persistence\Sql\SqlPersistenceEngine.cs:line 225
   at NEventStore.Persistence.PipelineHooksAwarePersistanceDecorator.GetSnapshot(String bucketId, String streamId, Int32 maxRevision) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\38b1777f2112a252\src\NEventStore\Persistence\PipelineHooksAwarePersistanceDecorator.cs:line 45
   at NEventStore.AccessSnapshotsExtensions.GetSnapshot(IAccessSnapshots accessSnapshots, String bucketId, Guid streamId, Int32 maxRevision) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\38b1777f2112a252\src\NEventStore\AccessSnapshotsExtensions.cs:line 49
   at CommonDomain.Persistence.EventStore.EventStoreRepository.GetSnapshot(String bucketId, Guid id, Int32 version) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\38b1777f2112a252\src\NEventStore\CommonDomain\Persistence\EventStore\EventStoreRepository.cs:line 147
   at CommonDomain.Persistence.EventStore.EventStoreRepository.GetById[TAggregate](String bucketId, Guid id, Int32 versionToLoad) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\38b1777f2112a252\src\NEventStore\CommonDomain\Persistence\EventStore\EventStoreRepository.cs:line 54
   at CommonDomain.Persistence.EventStore.EventStoreRepository.GetById[TAggregate](Guid id, Int32 versionToLoad) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\38b1777f2112a252\src\NEventStore\CommonDomain\Persistence\EventStore\EventStoreRepository.cs:line 44
   at CapraLibraShop.DataModel.Repositories.UserAggregateRepository.UserWithEmailExists(EmailAddress emailAddress) in D:\Projects\C#\CapraLibraShop\CapraLibraShop.DataModel\Repositories\UserAggregateRepository.cs:line 22
   at CapraLibraShop.Controllers.AccountController.Register() in D:\Projects\C#\CapraLibraShop\CapraLibraShop\Controllers\AccountController.cs:line 55
   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
```

Answer (score 4):

I literally found the answer two minutes after looking. But since I had a hard time Googling this answer I think it would be nice to place the answer here, instead of deleting the question.

I forgot to initialize the storage engine. I overlooked it because of the fluid syntax. The correct way to let NEventStore initialize the database is by including the `InitializeStorageEngine` method after you have selected the database type:

```
  this.EventStore = Wireup.Init()
               .LogToOutputWindow()
               .UsingInMemoryPersistence()
               .UsingSqlPersistence("DefaultConnection")
               .WithDialect(new MsSqlDialect())               
               .InitializeStorageEngine() // The oh so important line!
               .UsingJsonSerialization()
               .LogToOutputWindow()
               .Build();
```